# Laravel 5.3, CentOS, PHP 7 - How to connect MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, pdo, laravel-5.3, centos7

I have a project (`laravel5.3, php7, centos7`) pulling some data from `MSSQL` (not my choice btw). So, on XAMPP I was able to get it running successfully with ease using `pdo_sqlsrv`, however thats only for windows.

So how do I get it running on CentOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it myself after a lot of research.

---

{1}

Ive followed this guide to get `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` (step 2, Terminal):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php-rhel

`sqlsrv` was fine and could be seen in phpinfo, however `pdo_sqlsrv` couldnt be found.

Further, if you run `$ php -v` you get the error

```
Unable to load dynamic library '******/pdo_sqlsrv.so': undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0"
```

---

{2}

This let to major chase on how to fix it. Turns out the `pdo.so` was loading after `pdo_sqlsrv.so` as pdo.so loads from `/etc/php.d/` dir and I placed pdo_sqlsrv.so in the php.ini (as recom by the microsoft link). This I found by reading here https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/151

So I moved the following lines to `/etc/php.d/pdo.ini`:

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlsrv.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Problem solved

Comment: Took me forever to find this solution. Not sure why but I had to leave the extension=sqlsrv.so in /etc/php.ini